# How to specify button Icon using string name in Temporary drawer Material UI

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, navigation, material-ui, material-design

Hey guys I'm a newbie trying to make a material UI temporary drawer and by default the value of the `onClick` event is a string and I have no idea how to convert it into an icon.

```
return (
    <div>
        {['Home'].map((anchor) => (
            <React.Fragment key={anchor}>
                <Button onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, true)}>{anchor}</Button>
                <SwipeableDrawer
                    anchor={anchor}
                    open={state[anchor]}
                    onClose={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
                    onOpen={toggleDrawer(anchor, true)}
                >
                    {list(anchor)}
                </SwipeableDrawer>
            </React.Fragment>
        ))}
    </div>
);
```

As you can see: "HOME" is a string and what shows up on the site UI is just the "HOME" word that is a button. How do I format the code so the "HOME" button would not display a string but an icon instead. I'd be using MenuIcon from Material UI Icons to take its place. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Icon` component and pass the string to the children props. Before that, remember to add the [material icon](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#icon-font-icons) font to your html file

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
```

```js
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";

...

{["home", "star", "add_circle"].map((name) => (
  <IconButton>
    <Icon>{name}</Icon>
  </IconButton>
))}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 63991509/how-to-make-string-into-button-in-temporary-drawer-material-ui]

Comment: I haad no idea material-UI had font icons. I didn't even know they existed until now. Needless to say, it worked. Thank you Kind sir